# Update variable value once endpoint returns value

Tags: angular

I have a variable `newResidual` that gets used on my template from a service call `firstCall`. I then have another service call `secondCall` that fires off and updates that variables value. However that value does not reflect on my template. It shows undefined instead.

```
  newResidual: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.firstCall();
    this.secondCall();
  }

  firstCall() {
    this.avafService
      .GetAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustment(
        this.getAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustmentRequest
      )
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          this.loanAdjustmentResult =
            resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList;
          for (let i = 0; i < this.loanAdjustmentResult.length; i++) {
            if (this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureAllowed == "Y") {
              if (this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureType == "balloon") {
                this.loanAdjustmentList.push({
                  label: this.translations["balloon"] + this.newResidual, //VALUE HERE 
                  name: this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureType,
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
      );
  }

  secondCall() {
    this.avafService
      .CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment(this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest)
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          this.confirmData = resp.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment.calculatorResults;
          Object.keys(this.confirmData).forEach((key) => {
            const value = this.confirmData[key];
            this.calculatorResult = value;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.calculatorResult.length; i++) {
              if (this.calculatorResult[i].restructureType == "balloon") {
                this.newResidual = this.calculatorResult[i].newResidual; //Set value here
                console.log(this.newResidual);
              }
            }
          });
        }
      );
  }
```

How can I ensure that the `this.newResidual` value gets updated in my first call after the second call fires off?

Comment: Where are firstCall() and secondCall() methods called?

Comment: @Anglesvar sorry updated in question. Both in `ngOninit`

Comment: You want firstCall method to be fired after secondCall() that updates newResidual?

Comment: Is there a way to update `newResidual` without firing `firstCall ` after `secondCall`? Reason is there will be logic in the `firstCall ` method that will determine if the `secondCall` method should fire or not.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. You have to perform a check before executing firstCall method() and that should be done inside the `subscribe()` of `seconCall()`. This will trigger `firstCall()` method only on satisfying the conditions.

```
newResidual: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //this.firstCall();
    this.secondCall();
  }

  firstCall() {
    this.avafService
      .GetAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustment(
        this.getAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustmentRequest
      )
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          this.loanAdjustmentResult =
            resp.loanAdjustmentResult.loanAdjustmentList;
          for (let i = 0; i < this.loanAdjustmentResult.length; i++) {
            if (this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureAllowed == "Y") {
              if (this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureType == "balloon") {
                this.loanAdjustmentList.push({
                  label: this.translations["balloon"] + this.newResidual, //VALUE HERE 
                  name: this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureType,
                });
              }
            }
          }
        }
      );
  }

  secondCall() {
    this.avafService
      .CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment(this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest)
      .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          if(!resp) return;
          this.confirmData = resp.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustment.calculatorResults;
          Object.keys(this.confirmData).forEach((key) => {
            const value = this.confirmData[key];
            this.calculatorResult = value;
            for (let i = 0; i < this.calculatorResult.length; i++) {
              if (this.calculatorResult[i].restructureType == "balloon") {
                this.newResidual = this.calculatorResult[i].newResidual; 
                console.log(this.newResidual);
              }
            }
          }); //obj

         if(YOUR_CONDITION_GOES_IN_HERE && this.newResidual) //This can be used to determine if firstCall should be made or not. B`efore the control goes in here, 
           firstCall();
        }
       
      );
  }
```

Comment: Only when the firstCall fires do I know the condition. The condition is `this.loanAdjustmentResult[i].restructureAllowed == "Y"`. i'm thinking I can update the `this.loanAdjustmentList` in the second call as this is what I bind to my template

Comment: I think you are complicating things. There is a possibility that both methods might become dependent on each other. Something like firstCall() -> secondCall() -> firstCall() ... Try to modularize the logic into two different methods that only one method will depend on the other method.

Comment: I done this for each option in the array so it updates on the second call `let objIndex = this.loanAdjustmentList.findIndex((obj => obj.name == 'term'));
                this.loanAdjustmentList[objIndex].label = this.translations["term"] + this.newInstalment`

Answer (score 0):

Another aproach is use rxjs/operators: `GetAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustment` and `CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment` are async, so you can not be sure what finish fisrt, you need use rxjs/operators to use an unique susbcribe

As the two calls are independent (the first only need `this.getAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustmentRequest` and the second one only need `this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest`) you can use "forkJoin" (if the arguments of one call depending the result of the another one you need use switchMap)

So you can use

```
forkJoin([this.avafService
      .GetAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustment(
        this.getAVAFPreValidateLoanAdjustmentRequest
      ),
this.avafService
      .CalculateAVAFLoanAdjustment(this.calculateAVAFLoanAdjustmentRequest)
])
.subscribe(([responsePrevalidate,responseCalculate]:[any,any])=>{
       ..here you has the response to the two calls in separate variables...
       ..your code here... 
})
```